# Mocking a dao instance inside a service mthod

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following method:

```
public List<Author> getNewsAuthors() throws ServiceException, ConnectionException {
 try {
   logger.debug("Getting the NewsDAO instance");
   NewsDAO newsDAO = daoFactory.getNewsDAO(scopingDataSource);

   logger.debug("Getting news authors from the database");
   List<Author> authorList = newsDAO.getNewsAuthors();

   logger.debug("Returning all news authors");
   return authorList;
 }
 catch (SQLException e) {
   logger.error("Error in retrieving all news authors");
   if (isConnectionException(e.getLocalizedMessage())) {
   throw new ConnectionException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
 }
  else {
    throw new ServiceException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
 }
}
```

Can I mock the DAO instance inside the method call? Notice that the dao instance receives a data source in the constructor.

I am using EasyMock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

1. Create mock `DaoFactory` and `NewDAO` e.g.

`DaoFactory daoFactory = EasyMock.createMock(DaoFactory.class);
 NewsDAO newsDAO = EasyMock.createMock(NewsDAO.class);`

2. And then in your test you need to set the expections:

`EasyMock.expect(daoFactory.getNewsDAO(isA(ScopingDataSource.class))).andReturn(newsDAO);`